# Two different types of K-Fold Cross-Validation. Are both ways right ? Advantages or disavantages of each?

Tags: cross-validation, validation

For brevity let's say that k=10.

1º Scenario: I'll divide the training dataset in 10 parts of equal size, train my models in 9 groups joined together and measure some metrics on the remaining one, repeat this process ten times, each one of them is used in validation once. I think that's the most common way to do K-fold CV.

2º Scenario: I'll sample without replacement from my training dataset 10% of my sample size, train my models in the 90% that weren't chosen and validate on the first group. I'll repeat this process ten times, every time with a different seed.

Is there any difference in results between these methods ? in which situations one is better than the other ? Are there different names for each strategy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there different names for each strategy ?

The 1st strategy is what is usually called k-fold cross validation.
For the 2nd, naming is less consistent but I'd call it repeated or iterated set-validation.

> Is there any difference in results between these methods ?

There is a slight difference in that cases will be training case in a varying number of surrogate models, and also test cases for a varying number of surrogate models of the repeated/iterated set validation whereas any given case will always be training case for exactly k - 1 surrogate models and test case for exactly 1 surrogate model in k-fold CV without iterations/repetitions.

> in which situations one is better than the other ?

In practice, I would not expect any substantial difference in the uncertainty of the performance estimates. As long as the same number of surrogate models and test cases is evaluated, I haven't seen much of a difference between sampling with or without replacement.

Iterated/repeated set validation does offer one advantage over k-fold CV without iterations/repetitions: you can measure stability of the surrogate models' predictions by comparing predictions for cases that were tested more than once.
You can get this with k-fold as well, though, if you repeat/iterate the k-fold procedure (aka do more runs).
Also, this advantage doesn't come for free, if you do k repetitions of the set-validation, testing the same case multiple times means that some other case is never tested. I.e., your test sample size is < n.

---

- [Beleites, C.; Baumgartner, R.; Bowman, C.; Somorjai, R.; Steiner, G.; Salzer, R. & Sowa, M. G. Variance reduction in estimating classification error using sparse datasets, Chemom Intell Lab Syst, 79, 91 - 100 (2005).](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169743905000687)
- [Beleites, C. & Salzer, R.: Assessing and improving the stability of chemometric models in small sample size situations Anal Bioanal Chem, 2008, 390, 1261-1271.

  DOI: 10.1007/s00216-007-1818-6](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00216-007-1818-6)
- [Kim, J.-H. Estimating classification error rate: Repeated cross-validation, repeated hold-out and bootstrap , Computational Statistics & Data Analysis , 53, 3735 - 3745 (2009). DOI: 10.1016/j.csda.2009.04.009](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.csda.2009.04.009)

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, then please consider 
[upvoting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) 
and/or 
[accepting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) 
it.